# Space fiction novel about a woman who finds an alien who later may become attached to her as a soulmate

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, space

1. First character I remember is a woman (on a planet setting) who finds or defends from an alien who later may become attached to her as a soulmate.
2. Setting moves to space/space stations- The alien love interest (perhaps name similar to hawk or hawk like behaviors?) is animalistic, gives her a secret formula to mate her to him, and prolong her life. Potentially DNA altering.
3. Alien is a secret, deadly, powerful race that may be in hiding or gone.
4. Space politics involved, bounties.
5. Storytelling perspective possibly switches from woman.
6. Book was read in the last 10-12 years, and is part of a larger series.
7. No "Earth" setting recalled.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like David Weber's novel *The Path of the Fury* 1992, which he later expanded and published as *In Fury Born* in 2004.

*Path of the Fury* and the later re-issuance with new material and a full prequel novel as *In Fury Born.*

The alien was actually one of the Greek spirit/god/myth furies, and was the last of its kind, the others having just faded away.

Later she steals a high tech one of a kind AI controlled spaceship. (Thus the bounties on her.)

[image]

[image]

> UNLEASH THE FURY!

> Zhikotse. Shallingsport. Louvain. Sacred fields of battle on far-flung worlds where warriors of the Imperial Cadre spent blood and lives defending human civilization. Alicia DeVries was there; she led the charge. Her reward? Betrayal by a deceitful empire. Retirement to obscurity.

> Now Alicia is the only survivor of a brutal attack on her frontier-world family. Not since the mighty Achilles has the ancient spirit of the Fury Tisiphone taken up residence inside a human being. But not since Achilles has a warrior so skilled, so implacable, and possessing so much battle sense sprung up among the mass of humankind. Hero of the Empire. Holder of the Banner of Terra.
> There is a blood price to be paid. The Fury has awakened.

The Fury is more or less a spirit, who is able to keep her alive until help arrives to heal her, and then reactivate her super soldier implants/augments which had been deactivated when she was forced to retire.

She goes on a personal mission of vengence against the pirate/organization that raided the frontier world her family had settled on, killing her family (and a lot of the small population) in the raid.

Comment: So similar but not it. Thank you